# $x^2+3x^3+7x^4-5x^6-8x^7=0$ has one and only one positive root?

Tags: calculus, continuity

> $x^2+3x^3+7x^4-5x^6-8x^7=0$ has one and only one positive root? How to prove?

Clearly, if we graph it, it is easy to see. But for the proof? Factor out $x^2$, then?

Answer (score 4):

[Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) tells us there is one sign change, hence exactly one positive root. As the highest power is $x^7$ there must be at least one real root.

---

Observe you can factor out a $x^2$, where the other factor has an odd power of $x^5$ as Cameron Williams has suggested.

Comment: We know that there is a real root already since $x^2$ is a factor. It might be better to look at the factorized form instead and point to the odd power of $x^5$ instead.

Comment: Yep, I typed this answer too quickly.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Any elementary method?

Comment: I don't think it gets any more elementary than Descartes in this case, unfortunately @xldd. It's where my mind went to first but Toby Mak beat me to it by moments. Getting information about roots of polynomials is a very, very difficult problem. Descartes is one of very few results that works in general for real numbers. The other main result that always works is the fundamental theorem of algebra, but that doesn't tell you much about the roots themselves.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Any useful ideas using only continuity (and the fundamental theorem of algebra)?

Comment: @xldd Well if you could factor it, there's no question about where the roots are! But factoring a quintic is *hard*.